# Android: RecyclerView within vertical viewpager

Tags: android, scroll, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, vertical-scrolling

I want to implement a recyclerview within a vertical viewpager. My current layout looks like the following

```
VerticalViewpager
- Fragment1
    - ImageView
- Fragment2 
    - RecyclerView
```

If I swipe from Fragment1 to Fragment2 everything works fine. I am able to scroll within the recyclerview up and down. The problem occurs if I try to swipe/scroll back to Fragment1.

If the user has scrolled to the top of the recyclerview, I would like to forward the next "Up"-Scroll event to the vertical viewpager. I have tried overriding the `onInterceptTouchEvent` method, but unfortunately still no success. Any ideas out there? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Hi! I need to do exactly the same thing, any luck?

Comment: Hi @Caique, unfortunately no solution that works in all our cases. The suggestion from Mr. India was helpful to us, but as I already mentioned in my comment below his suggestion this solution doesn't work every time.

Comment: Thks for the answer. What I did was: I Overwrited the onTouch of the recyclerview, got the speed from ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_MOVE and ACTION_UP, and if the speed is > 500 (is going up with some velocity) I go back one position on viewpager. It's working pretty good. I'll post as an answer with the code, maybe could help you

Comment: That would be really nice. As soon as you post it, I will try your solution :)

Answer (score 3):

You need do disable the `scroll`. Try using `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`

Comment: Hi, thans for your answer. I tried it out and it works...sometimes :D If I reached the top of the recyclerview I have to scroll at least four or five times, till the VerticalViewpager gets the event and scrolls back to Fragment1. Any idea what causes this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

1) You need to use support library 23.2.0 (or) above
2) and recyclerView height will be wrap_content.
3) recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)

But by doing this the recycler pattern don't work. (i.e all the views will be loaded at once because wrap_content needs the height of complete recyclerView so it will draw all recycler views at once. No view will be recycled). Try not to use this pattern util unless it is really required.

Answer (score 1):

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrolled (RecyclerView recyclerView,int dx, int dy) {
                int topRowVerticalPosition = (recyclerView == null || recyclerView.getChildCount() == 0) ? 0 : recyclerView.getChildAt(0).getTop();
                if (topRowVerticalPosition >= 0) {
                    //top position
                }
            }
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged (RecyclerView recyclerView,int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }
            });
```

By using this code you can find whether the user is in top position. In the position you can make the view pager to move to your desired position.

Comment: The detection doesn't work if the user is already in the top position in the recycler view and tries to scroll up even higher to trigger the viewpager.

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann:: try declaring the **int topRowVerticalPosition = 0;** as public.

Comment: I can't set the variable to public inside the onScroll Method. It would make any sense here anyway, wouldn't it?

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann:: you can check with this also **recyclerView.getChildCount() == 0** to find the child count.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access `VerticalViewPager` from RecyclerView, you can extend RecyclerView and check `canScrollVertically(-1)` and forward touch event to viewpager

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest migrating to ViewPager2 first, since it natively allows for vertical scrolling, and then using the solution provided by the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration#nested-scrollables) to supported nested scrollable elements.

Essentially, you need to add the [NestedScrollableHost](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/blob/master/ViewPager2/app/src/main/java/androidx/viewpager2/integration/testapp/NestedScrollableHost.kt) to your project and then wrap your RecyclerView with it, similar to below:

```
    <NestedScrollableHost
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" />

    </NestedScrollableHost>
```

Note that this solution only works for the layout your provided where the RecyclerView would be an immediate child of one of your ViewPager's screen. This solution won't work for other RecyclerView that are nested in the main RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

You need to forbid nestedscroll in parent scrollview
i have new implement for this , you can try the below link https://github.com/liuxiaocong/VerticalViewpage

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The answer from Mr.India was helpful, but as your commented, it only worked sometimes.

What I did was

```
recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public float speed;
            public VelocityTracker mVelocityTracker;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int index = event.getActionIndex();
                int action = event.getActionMasked();
                int pointerId = event.getPointerId(index);

                switch (action) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        if(mVelocityTracker == null) {
                            mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
                        }
                        else {
                            mVelocityTracker.clear();
                        }
                        mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if(mVelocityTracker != null) {
                            mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);
                            mVelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000);
                            speed = VelocityTrackerCompat.getYVelocity(mVelocityTracker, pointerId);
                        }
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        int topRowVerticalPosition = (recyclerView == null || recyclerView.getChildCount() == 0) ? 0 : recyclerView.getChildAt(0).getTop();
                        if(speed > 500 && topRowVerticalPosition >= 0) {
                            ReaderFragmentParent parent = (ReaderFragmentParent) getActivity();
                            ReaderPager pager = parent.getPager();
                            if(pager != null) {
                                pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem()-1);
                            }

                        }
                        return false;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        mVelocityTracker.recycle();
                        break;
                }


                return false;
            }
        });
```

On the ACTION_UP I verify if the speed > 500, it means it's going up on a considered speed and the topRowVerticalPosition means it is on top of the recyclerview. Then I get the ViewPager and setCurrentItem to previous item.

it's a bit of a dirty hack, but it was the only way I found to make look like a good scrolling between pages on the Vertical ViewPager

Answer (score 0):

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled (RecyclerView recyclerView,int dx, int dy) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged (RecyclerView recyclerView,int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

                if (!mRecyclerView.canScrollVertically(-1) && newState == 0) {

                    Log.e("canScrollVertically", mRecyclerView.canScrollVertically(-1)+"");

                    verticalViewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
                }
            }
        });
```